# Round ALL Results in SQL Table

Tags: mysql, rounding

I wrote the script and was able to get my results, but need help rounding all of them down 1 decimal place in the sum(assign hours) table and 2 in the sum (assign charge) table. None of the round functions as I have seen here work.

Here is the code that I used and generates results:

```
SELECT  ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, Sum(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_HOURS) AS SumOfASSIGN_HOURS, Sum(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
FROM    EMPLOYEE, ASSIGNMENT
WHERE   EMPLOYEE.EMP_NUM = ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM
GROUP BY    ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME
```

Thank you!
Remi

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please check your data you might have ASSIGN_HOURS and ASSIGN_CHARGE value null for some employees.

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly looking for [`Format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function. It would format the resultant Sum number with expected no of decimal places. So, even `FORMAT(3.5,2)` will return `3.50`:

```
SELECT  ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM, 
        EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, 
        FORMAT(Sum(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_HOURS),1) AS SumOfASSIGN_HOURS,
        FORMAT(Sum(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_CHARGE),2) AS SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
FROM    EMPLOYEE, ASSIGNMENT
WHERE   EMPLOYEE.EMP_NUM = ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM
GROUP BY ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME
```